# MVC- After ajax request Page cannot be refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

on my view page , i am passing some values to controller by ajax request , on controller action, after checking , redirecting message value to view's controller.Adding message to model and pasisng model to view again with new model value.On second time( postback) model values passed to view as Json but new model value(which is message) cannot be catch by javascript.In my code it is Model.INFO

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("TeamSaveChanges", "Administrator")',
            data: {
                ID: '@Model.ID',
                doctorID: doctorValue,
                nurseID:nurseValue,
                driverID:driverValue,
                technicianID: technicianValue

            },
            dataType: "text",
            success: function () { alert("@Model.INFO")},
           error: function () { alert("Error occured!!!") }
        });
```

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult TeamSaveChanges(Guid ID, Guid? doctorID, Guid? nurseID, Guid? driverID, Guid? technicianID)
    {
        try
        {

            using (var client = SoapProxyFactory.CreateDSrvGDSoapClient())
            {
                var emptyTeam = Guid.Empty;
                var ambID = client.getAmbulanceIDbyTeamID(ID);
                var baseresult = client.checkAmblanceTeamsforDuplicateMembers(ambID, ID);


                if (doctorID == emptyTeam && nurseID == emptyTeam &&   driverID == emptyTeam  && technicianID == emptyTeam  )
                {
                    var result = client.EditTeamMembers(ID, doctorID, nurseID, driverID, technicianID);
                    if (result)
                        throw new Exception("saved");
                }
                else 
                {
                    foreach (var item in baseresult)
                {
                        if(item.DOCTORCODE == doctorID && item.NURSECODE == nurseID &&  item.DRIVERCODE == driverID && item.TECHNICIANCODE == technicianID)
                            throw new Exception("The team with Same Members is exist." + "<p>(" + item.TEAMCODE + ")</p>");
                    }

                    var result = client.EditTeamMembers(ID, doctorID, nurseID, driverID, technicianID);
                    if (result)
                        throw new Exception("saved");
                }       
                  catch (Exception exp)
        {
            string message = exp.Message;
            return RedirectToAction("TeamMembers", "Administrator", new { ID = ID, message = message });


        }

   [OutputCache(Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.None)]
    public ActionResult TeamMembers(Guid? ID,string message)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ID.HasValue())
               return RedirectToAction("Ambulance");


            using (var client = SoapProxyFactory.CreateDSrvALLSoapClient())
            {
               Guid id  = ID.Value;

                var clientGD = SoapProxyFactory.CreateDSrvGDSoapClient();
               var result = client.GetTeamMembers(id);
               result.INFO = message;
                if (message != null)
               {
                   result.INFO = message;
                   return  Json(result,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
               }

             return View(result);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
success: function () { alert("@Model.INFO")},
```

Will only pull in the INFO of the model once because it renders the server value in the client.  If you are expecting it to change, then you have to pass the result back to success, and accept the new value as such:

```
success: function (d) { alert(d); },
```

To return a value to it you have to return from the action:

```
return Content("SOMEVAL"); // or PartialView or something that is string data
```

However, redirecting to action isn't going to return a response to the caller, and may not be handled properly through AJAX, so I'm not 100% sure what the question is...

Comment: Yes,it was exactly what i am looking for.I just needed to (JSON.parse) to parse returned data and get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use AJAX for this? What is happening is your script is firing a request off to your controller, which sends the response back as data, not a redirect to a new webpage.

Just create a form that POSTs those variables to your controller in typical MVC fashion, you'll get the result you want.

Comment: It is a page that are some combobox with values and save button.After selecting values on combobox,when click save,values are passing to controller by ajax.I need to use ajax  because combobox widgets are javascript based(KendoUI).When a value select on combobox,catches it is select event and doing some process.After that sending data by Ajax.

Comment: Then you should use perform a redirect on the client side in your success handler.